# Lie someone down or a transitive alternative

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine a kid who is not able to lie down on a bed or a patient who is unable to lie down on a bed when refers to a doctor themselves. How the doctor should ask the kid's mother or someone who has come to doctor along with the patient (I've no idea what would such a person be called in English!) to help them lie down on the bed to examine them?
Does my self-made sentence below work:

> - Lie the kid / the ill/sick person on the bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible sentences that convey the meaning you wish are:

> Help the sick person (to) lie (down) on the bed so I may examine them.

(the words 'to' and 'down' in the sentence above may be included or not as desired)

> Lay the sick person on the bed for an examination.

Comment: Mark, wasn't it better to say: "Lay the sick person **down** on the bed for an examination."?

Comment: Is it possible to replace "lay" with "stretch" without any change in meaning @Mark?

Comment: Using 'down' would work. 'Down' implies either that the bed is lower than the patient is before laying in the bed or else pushing the patient downward during the process. Stretch has a similar meaning with lay, but also may imply pulling the patient's extremities to make them longer.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to add "stretch" - if someone is lying on a bed, the normal assumption is that they're lying at full length.  I would only use *stretch* if there were some reason to think they might *not* be at full length and you specifically needed them to be.